# VBA/Excel - Find Numbers And Move Range

Tags: vba, excel

Go easy on me - brand new to VBA. I am having trouble getting this simple process complete, and my brain is scrambled after searching and searching. I am working with almost 50,000 rows of data. I need to...

1. Check column C to see if it contains numbers.
2. If it does not - do nothing.
3. If it does contain numbers - cut data from adjacent row (column D).
4. Paste this into column A.

   `Sub MoveRange()
   If IsEmpty(Range("C2:C40001").Value) = False Then
   Range("D2:D40001").Select
   Selection.Cut
   Range("A2").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   End If
   End Sub`

I have been able to hand write the cut and paste portion - that works fine. I must be missing something on the 'IsEmpty' portion of things. The cells in column C are either blank, or contain numbers - there are no mixed characters. I assume there is something I'm not setting correctly, to flag the numbers?

Right now the code runs, but it moves ALL data from column D into column A.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to loop through each cell: for each cell in range: do something:next cell is the way you need, you're checking the column being blank, or a large portion of it i believe

Comment: This is ambiguous.....Do you want to copy the entire block if **every** cell in the block has a number or if **even one** cell in the block has a number or **only those cells having numbers** to be copied ??

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified. I want to move the data in the adjacent cells - ONLY if the cells in column C have numbers. i.e. If C18 contains a number, then I want to move D18 to A18. @davesexcel - That was incredibly quick and helpful. The loop portion works - but it copies and pastes - not cuts and pastes. Also - it needs to go D2 To A2 - these got pasted one after another. Sorry I can't modify this to work myself, I'm not well versed in VBA yet.

Answer (score 1):

Array solution, probably the most efficient for large datasets even though it has a loop:

**EDIT** Updated code to perform a "cut" result instead of a "copy" result and put results in same row they were cut from.

```
Sub tgr_Array()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim aResults As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet     'Change to actual sheet if necessary
    ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Rows.Count).Clear  'Clear previous results, if any

    With ws.Range("C2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data
        ReDim aResults(1 To .Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
        aData = .Resize(, 2).Value
    End With

    For i = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
        If IsNumeric(aData(i, 1)) And Len(Trim(aData(i, 1))) > 0 Then
            aResults(i, 1) = aData(i, 2)
            aData(i, 2) = vbNullString
        End If
    Next i

    ws.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(aResults, 1)).Value = aResults
    ws.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(aData, 1), UBound(aData, 2)).Value = aData

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too, but the data is copied and pasted - not cut and pasted. Also, the new data is one row after another in column A. I'm looking for a way to have it displayed where it is in column D - just moved over to column A. i.e. D18 To A18, D30 To A30, etc. I think the offset value can do this, I just don't know how to properly implement it.

Comment: Bingo! That works great, and I very much appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a loop or filter to get the none blank cells

```
Sub MoveRangeUsingAloop()
    Dim rng As Range, LstRw As Long, c As Range

    LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("C2:C" & LstRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    For Each c In rng
        Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = c.Offset(, 1)
    Next c

End Sub
Sub UsingFilter()
    Dim rng As Range, LstRw As Long

    LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("C2:C" & LstRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    Columns("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Set rng = Range("D2:D" & LstRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rng.Copy Range("A2")
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = 0


End Sub
```

Comment: Yes,I assumed 1st row has a header-@Jeeped

Comment: That was incredibly quick and helpful. Both code blocks work - but it copies and pastes - not cuts and pastes. Also - the data needs to go D2 To A2, D18 To A18 - these paste one after another, in column A. Sorry I can't modify this to work myself, I'm not well versed in VBA yet.